# XML document conversion

Tags: c#, xml

I am an intermediate level c# programmer and need help with XML documents.

I need to do the following:

1. Parse a fairly large XML document A
2. Extract specific elements and values
3. Store these values in a new XML document B(The element names will be different)

XML document B elements will have different name but same values extracted from Document A.

Can someone help with the best design to achieve this?

Should I use data contracts / serialization , should I use enums to store XML elements……….

Please give me an overview off the best way to achieve the above or direct me to an example

Comment: Does it have to be a service? If not, don't bother with data contracts. System.XML will make this a breeze.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? XML manipulation is very common and there are plenty of resources for .NET about them.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a service.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be reading XML, and then creating XML based on that then you may want to consider using XSLT. This is a method of transforming XML docs into new XML docs using XQuery and XPath. If you're going to be doing this type of thing in the future with XML as well then it's worth learning.

Here's a link to a tutorial on code project:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460968/XSLT-2-0-programming-basics

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)

If you are strictly just translating one XML document to another, you might also look at writing an XSLT to do the translation.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the `XmlDocument` class and XPath

[some xpath examples are here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp)

Here's an example of putzing around with XML documents, getting values from one document and putting them in another.

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("filename.xml");

string val = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//ElementName").Attributes["attributeName"].Value;

XmlDocument xDoc2 = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement ele = xDoc2.CreateElement("ElementName2");
XmlAttribute att = xDoc2.CreateAttribute("attributeName2");
att.Value = val;
ele.Attributes.Append(att);
xDoc2.AppendChild(ele);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some pseudo-code and info. I can't be to specific since you didn't provide any info.

1 - Load your `Xml A` using `XmlDocument`.

```
var aDoc = new XmlDocument();
aDoc.Load("someFile.xml");
```

2 - Since you said you want a specific node you can use [xPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) to extract that node. (The xPath is just an example)

```
XmlNode extractedNode = aDoc.SelectSingleNode(/rootNode/parentNode);
```

3 - Now you have your node in extracted, time to put it in a new document `bDoc` (loaded exactly like the `aDoc`).

```
XmlNode rootNode = bDoc.DocumentElement;
rootNode.AppendChild(extractedNode);
```

Very basic, not specific at all but all I can come up with your ccurrent question.